# Steps needed to use MySQL database with Play framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm new to Play framework. I'm trying to configure MySQL database as a datasource to be used with Play Ebeans.

Could you some one please explain the steps that are needed to configure MySQL with Play 2.0 framework (like, downloading drivers, adding dependency etc).

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Look at [this page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaDatabase) from Play's documentation. It says:

> Other than for the h2 in-memory database, useful mostly in development mode, Play 2.0 does  not provide any database drivers. Consequently, to deploy in production you will have to add your database driver as an application dependency.
>
> For example, if you use MySQL5, you need to add a dependency for the connector:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    ...
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
    ...
)
```

SBT will download the driver for you. You should also check out the [section on managing dependencies](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies).

To connect to MySQL, you will also need to change some settings in your `application.conf`:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="mysql://root:secret@localhost/myDatabase"
```

Comment: thanks. Once that is done, what would be the configuration changes should I make in application.conf file? (db.default.driver, db.default.url, etc)

Comment: @Carsten, giving url without quotes will fail

Comment: play framework 2.1.1 here . after updating the build.sbt, you should give the command 'update' in the play terminal

Comment: Nowadays, it should be added into the build.sbt at the root-level of the project, e.g.: libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.28",
  cache
)

Comment: When you get it working you should also read the thread pool section of the docs and update your config accordingly since jdbc is a blocking API. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools

Comment: After including the above settings, running 'dependencies' as opposed to 'update' (mentioned by @KinjalDixit) in the play console was required.

Comment: should possibly be updated with the new build.sbt command ,or a version outlining?

Answer (score 94):

As Carsten wrote it can be fetched from documentation, however here's a summary:

make sure you have the dependency configured in `/project/Build.scala`

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)
```

Add a proper config of the DB (replace default H2 config) in `/conf/application.conf`:

(don't remove encoding from URL):

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/your_db_name?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=your_login
db.default.password=your_pass
```

in the same file find and make sure this line is NOT commented:

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

That's all, restart your app (or run in dev mode), then it will create a DDL and ask you to apply it.

Comment: Can you please update the documentation too here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/documentation/manual/javaGuide/main/sql/JavaDatabase.md so that everyone can benefit? Thanks!

Comment: Other things to consider is to make sure that MySQL is not limited to socket only connections (Mac/Linux) and that `localhost` may need to be replaced with `127.0.0.1`. In specifict terms, using [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) (an Oracle-free drop in replacement for MySQL) from MacPorts I had to comment out [skip-networking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html) in `my.cnf` and use the IP address instead of `localhost` to have Play successfully connect.

Comment: Why did you add jdbc to the beginning of the db url?

Comment: @BenMorganIO cause we need to use JDBC driver, such a syntax, nothing more

Comment: I'm confused. What is the purpose of "jdbc:mysql:" in the URL? Is "jdbc:mysql" the name of the database?

Answer (score 10):

I am using play 2.2.0 and I just had to add the following line to build.sbt in project's root folder.

```
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"
```

And play automatically downloads the driver. It seems Build.scala is not needed for this anymore. Changes to application.conf should be applied as the above commentators have mentioned.

Comment: This just saved me.  Using Play 2.10.3 and this was the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thank you!!! For people who need detailed instructions like me, you basically go to build.sbt and add that line to `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(jdbc,anorm,cache,"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27")`

Comment: For people like me, do not forget to stop the ./activator, and then run it again :)

Answer (score 8):

Most of the methods of accessing a mysql database that I've come across do not explain how to establish a connection and retrieve data from within the Model. In my application, I am using both mongoDB and an external mysql database. So here's how I did (the mysql side of) things:

1. For Play 2.3.3, in the build.sbt file add the mysql specific line in the libraryDependencies:

   ```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"
   )
   ```
2. In the /conf/application.conf file add this:

   ```
   db.myotherdb.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   db.myotherdb.url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/NameOfOtherDB?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
   db.myotherdb.user = MyOtherDbUSername
   db.myotherdb.password = MyOtherDbPass
   ```

   You can replace "myotherdb" by "default" in case you want to use the default database or with any other name that you want to use. Replace "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" with the IP address of the server where your database is located (in case of an external database) or localhost (or 127.0.0.1) for local database. Replace "NameOfOtherDB" with the name of the database that you want to use, the "MyOtherDbUSername" with your database username and "MyOtherDbPass" with your database password.
3. Inside your Model (/app/models/MyModel.scala) add this:

   ```
   val connection = DB.getConnection("myotherdb")
   ```
4. Create the statement, the query and execute it:

   ```
   val statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
   val query = "SELECT * FROM myTableName"
   val resultset = statement.executeQuery(query)
   ```
5. Then you can continue with whatever you want to do with the retrieved data. For example:

   ```
   while (resultset.next()) {
       resultset.getString("columnName")
   }
   ```

   Where "columnName" is the name of the DB table column/field that you want to retrieve.

Last but not least, I would like to note that you might want to close the connection by calling *close()*

Comment: Your example is very useful. How would it look like for Play Java?

Answer (score 7):

Got stuck with my MySQL configuration until I found this.

Most important things taken from @biesior answer:

- Add MySQL connector/J in project's dependency (which is inside `/project/Build.scala`)
- After adding dependency, run `play dependencies` to resolve newly added MySQL connector/J dependency
- Uncomment default ebean configuration line `ebean.default="models.*"`
- Configure MySQL database correctly with proper character encoding `db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://www.sample.com:3306/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  db.default.user=playuser
  db.default.pass=playuser`

It saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

### **Play 2.4.3 & MYSQL 5.7.9**

I was able to get this working by piecing together bits of info from all the previous answers. So here is another one, that is hopefully more up to date or useful to those with a similar environment.

**Environment Details:** (*this is what I am using*)

- Play 2.4.3 this comes with *activator-1.3.7-minimal*
- JDK8, you should already have this as I don't think this version of play works with JDK7
- MYSQL 5.7.9

**appication.conf**

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testSchema?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=yourDBUserName
db.default.password=yourDBUserPass
```

**Note:**

- testSchema in the URL is your database name, if you are using something like [MYSQL workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) you will see this listed under the SCHEMAS section. I called mine testSchema. Others may call it something like "myDatabase"
- The port should be the MYSQL port. Not your application port. I put `3306` in the example because that is usually the default for MYSQL.

**build.sbt**

Add this line below to your build.sbt file. This should go after the `libraryDependencies ++= Seq()` declaration.

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

**Finally**

- run this command from your project root -> `activator reload`
- restart your appplication

Answer (score 4):

For **play 2.3.1**, Follow these steps.

1) Add MySQL connector/J in project's dependency (which is inside /project/build.sbt)

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc, javaEbean, "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.29"
```

2) Uncomment default ebean configuration line ebean.default="models.*"

3) Configure MySQL database correctly with proper character encoding

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    //this is com. and not org.
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=playuser
db.default.pass=playuser
```

4) Most Imp. Run a **reload** command  in the console.

Comment: This works all perfectly fine for me locally. But when I create a dist package, upload the package to a Ubuntu server and try to start the application I get `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for mysql://...`.

Comment: try putting your mysql driver in classpath.

Comment: I've added it to libraryDependencies in my build.sbt (which made it work locally) and on the server I've installed it with `sudo apt-get install mysql-client; sudo apt-get install libmysql-java` put `export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar` and also added it to `/etc/environment` (as described on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JDBCAndMySQL). It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For play java project Using SBT

Change the libraryDependency to llok like this in "build.sbt"

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"
)
```

Run your project using "activator run"

Play will down required jdbc connector.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in latest play framework 2.4.x with activator 1.3.6.

Here are the steps. 
I Followed the steps described here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDatabase

Here is my `application.conf`

```html
# MySQL DB Configuration
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://{hostname or ipaddres}/{db name}?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.username=username  // Note that user id deprecated, instead use username. Though that is not a major issue
db.default.password="password"

# JPA Configurations
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
PlayKeys.externalizeResources = false

# JavaEbean configuration
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

Here is `build.sbt`

```html
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  evolutions,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"
)
```

`plugins.sbt`

```html
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Here is the important step.

> After configuring above steps, go to command line, stop your activator and run the command `activator run`. In my situation, I was keep getting the error `unable to find mysql drivers`. After running the `activator run`, activator would actually download the MySQL drivers and would resolve the dependencies. That is the important step that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me this work, add this below line into your dependencies:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

Here is the code:

```scala
import java.sql.Connection

val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/world"
val username = "root"
val password = "root"
var connection: Connection = null

try {
    // make the connection
    Class.forName(driver)
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

    // create the statement, and run the select query
    val statement = connection.createStatement()
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id , name FROM bar")

    val sql: SqlQuery = SQL("select * from products order by name asc")

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        val id = resultSet.getString("id")
        val name = resultSet.getString("name")
        println(id, name)
    }
} catch {
case e: Exception => println("exception caught: " + e);
}
connection.close()
```