# Play! framework - ORM

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, playframework-2.0

From the *Play!* framework docs:

> **There is no built-in JPA** implementation in Play 2.0; you can choose any available implementation. For example, to use Hibernate, just add the dependency to your project:

- What are my option rather than Hibernate?
- What do you think is well-suited for a message-board website?
- I understood Hibernate has a little overhead, is that right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [Ebean](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaEbean) ORM built-in the Play 2.0 doesn't it meet your needs?

All you need to start working with it is just uncoment few lines in `application.conf`, check this description for MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007515/1066240

Comment: does Ebean efficient (or high-performance) and easy to use?
and does it stable and well-maintained?

Comment: @socksocket: It's lightweight and efficient, it's much younger than Hibernate so it's hard to find many one-to-one comparisons, however I saw many posts that guys previously using Hibernate were enthusiastic about Ebean. You need to perform custom research, I was using it in few recent projects and hadn't any bigger problems.

Comment: @socksocket: Ach, and yes is definitely easy to use. Check the refference guide in PDF: http://www.avaje.org/ebean/documentation.html

Answer (score 3):

There is also squeryl http://squeryl.org/. Here is a nice tutorial on getting started: http://www.artima.com/articles/play2_scala_squeryl.html