# play framework - Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] - intelli J

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Steps needed to use MySQL database with Play framework 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007029/steps-needed-to-use-mysql-database-with-play-framework-2-0)

I am trying to run the Play 2.0 framework application in IntelliJ but it is giving an error : Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]. But it was running good in Eclipse.

I looked in conf file many times but couldn't get any find error on that.

```
      db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/resource_planning"
      db.default.user=root
      db.default.pass=password
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Voting to reopen, this is a specific case. In particular, I ran into it after following the steps in the "duplicate" question. My particular problem was failing to restart Play after adding the jdbc config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have full recipe for configuring MySQL DB:

- [Steps needed to use MySQL database with Play framework 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007029/steps-needed-to-use-mysql-database-with-play-framework-2-0/10007515#10007515)

Answer (score 6):

Just I got the answer !!

forgot to include dependency - `"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"` in `Build.scala` file

Comment: hi, if the document is clear enough, why would I ask in stackoverflow. thanks.

Comment: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaDatabase Last paragraphe of the page.

Comment: OK. thanks. I figured it later. I am get used Play-1.2.4, forgot about while writing my code. anyways thanks once again !