# How to use DATABSE_URL in Play 2.0 (Scala) for local connection to mysql

Tags: database, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to Play framework. I'm trying to configure MySQL database as a datasource to be used with Play.

i have done following setting to connect mysql database to play..

> db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=formdemo&token=3882f545563c7df106e1daf21515e1b7#PMAURL:db=formdemo&server=1&target=db_structure.php&token=3882f545563c7df106e1daf21515e1b7"

---

but i am getting following configuration error.

> play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to
> database [default]]

---

I am not able to connect my wamp localhost database to play.
How do I modify the configuration file to use a mysql database as opposed to an in-memory version. Do I need to setup an entirely separate DB or can I modify the db.default.url property?

I'm using Play! 2.1.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007029/steps-needed-to-use-mysql-database-with-play-framework-2-0/10007131#10007131 It looks like you want to point to phpmyadmin somehow. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved with issue. Thank You for your guidance.

Few lines to Put.
dependency

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
```

Conf

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/FORMDEMO?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=""
```

Follow the reference,
http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/01/28/play-framework-2-0-connectivity-with-mysql-in-scala/

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be in this structure:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="mysql://username:password@localhost/formdemo"
```

If you didn't set the default password, it is usually root with no password, like this:

```
db.default.url="mysql://username:@localhost/formdemo"
```