# Play cannot resolve MySQL Driver

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

I just upgraded to Play 2.4 and for whatever reason I'm unable to load up the JDBC MySQL driver. Here is what I have in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.+",
  evolutions

)
```

After refreshing (IntelliJ) and running the application, I still receive the following error

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I've searched for any potential issues, but haven't come across any. Is there some bug with sbt that I don't know about?

Comment: try defining the actual version `"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.6"`.and dont forget to `clean`

Comment: Same issue after specifying version and running activator clean

Comment: Show us also how do you configure the connection in `application.conf` maybe there's some error, also check IntelliJ's Event Log for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably (just shooting) you have a typo in your `application.conf` - it should be: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with exact version (not `org.mysql...`)

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/your_db_name?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=your_login
db.default.password=your_pass
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007515/1066240) or in the [2.4.x docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDatabase#MySQL-database-engine-connection-properties)

Comment: I don't know why I was thinking org instead of com. That was the issue. Thanks a ton!