# How to use ebean and mysql in play framework?

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, playframework, ebean

Im trying to create small CRUD application using **play-java** template.
Im using **typesafe activator** through cmd I create new project so now i want enable ebean and have to change mysql database. im using `activator 1.3.6,`
for sql im using my **phpmyadmin sql 5.6.20** i googled and i did everything like documentary but still i couldn't solve my problem i couldn't add **ebean** my project and i couldn't connect **mysql** connector i did changes using this links
[Ebean](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean) [Mysql](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDatabase)  [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007029/steps-needed-to-use-mysql-database-with-play-framework-2-0) but no use i wasted 3 days then i used play2-crud template [enter link description here](https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud-activator) in this i can use eban but i dont know how to enable mysql and im using **INTELLIJ** IDE if anyone expert help me

Comment: What errors do you have? I also use https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean as a roadmap and got it working within few hours.

Comment: i create ne project ok using play-java then i uncommand in plugin.sbt file 'addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")' ok then in build.sbt i chnged (Playjava) to (Playjava, PlayEbean) when i change PlayEbean red color and thr i have add javaebean under libraryDependencies both eban red color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To enable MySQL**

in the `application.conf` file:

```
# Database configuration using MySQL database engine
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydataabse"
db.default.username=yourusername
db.default.password="yourpassword"
```

and you also need to add MySQL connector to the `build.sbt` `libraryDependencies`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)
```

**To enable Ebean**

Add Ebean plugin In to the `project\plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Enable this plugin in the `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

Configure Ebean in the `conf\application.conf` to take models from your model package:

```
ebean.default = ["my.models.*"]
```

Comment: really thanks its running without any error befor i used 5.6.20 i think that is the problem and i want knw how to enable **eban** when i extend model class to **Model** i want import play.db.ebean.Model. i think u got it what im asking

Comment: but you write als that when you are using different template then you are able to run ebean but "i dont know how to enable mysql"

Comment: do not forget to recompile project after the changes.

Comment: the way i  changed three places after i compile through CMD im getting this error 'Play ebean module has been replaced with an external Play ebean plugin.
See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 for details.'

Comment: You need to "remove javaEbean from your libraryDependencies in build.sbt". I saw you add this "have add javaebean under libraryDependencies " - remove it

Comment: name := """play-java-app"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc,javaEbean,cache, javaWs, "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18")
// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
fork in run := true` here PlayBean red color and Javaeban diffrent color apart Javajdbc

Comment: please, remove "javaEbean" form the libraryDependencies: "javaJdbc,javaEbean,cache," => "javaJdbc,cache,"

Comment: yes i removed still PlayEbean is red color and when i try to extend model class to Model i cant find play.db.ebean.Model package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95055/discussion-between-hamel-raj-and-andriy-kuba).

Comment: Take a look int the chat again

Comment: Thankyou alot two both of u :)